# QGIS raster calculator error: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I just made a simple subtraction between two raster layers and got the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\raster_transparency\rastertransparency.py", line 150, in layerChanged
>       maxValue = int(stat.maximumValue)
>   OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Both layers are Geotiff 32 bit pixel depth and floating point pixel type.

Is this a bug in the raster calculator or does anyone have suggestions to why I cannot subtract the two layers?
Running QGIS 2.10.1

Comment: In your output layer you have an infinity symbol after these calculations. Python tries to perform int(infinity) ant it can't be done.

Comment: hmm okay, thanks for your answer! 
Is that something I can change manually?
I also just found out that QGIS say the layer min-max is -1.66 - 392.71 gdal info say its -6.7 - 562 (which is right). I dont understand wy QGIS show the wrong value. If I load the raster to ArcMap the right values are shown

Comment: Ok so about QGIS displaying wrong Min/max is bc it calculates by default is 2% - 98%, see the 'Cumulative count cut' option in the 'Load min/max values' section of the dialog box.

Comment: In `C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\raster_transparency\rastertransparency.py` you can try to manually change this line `maxValue = int(stat.maximumValue)` to something like that `maxValue = stat.maximumValue`. I think it is qgis function bug, wrong band statistics.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried what you said. Replaced maxValue = int(stat.maximumValue) with maxValue = stat.maximumValue. Did the same with the minimumValue. Unfortunately it came back with the same error but displaying maxValue = stat.maximumValue instead. I know some people in my office has worked with the same tif file and done some raster calc with it in QGIS so I wonder if I have a bug in my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to use the built in raster calculator. However using the SAGA raster calculator in the processing toolbox did the job.